# How to draw the graph by using transformation of graphs

Tags: calculus

$y=|1+e^{|x|} - e^{-x}|$. I am getting problem in drawing graph of $e^{|x|} - e^{-x}$. Is there any rule to draw $f (x) + g (x) , f (x)-g (x)$ graph.